# how to get kendoui grid popup add/edit form created from kendo template, show the correct title for add and edit operations?

Tags: templates, popup, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I can't seem to find a simple way to set the title on a popup add and edit form launched from the kendoui grid, when it is created using a custom template.  When I tried the following example, both Add and Edit operations had "Edit" in the title bar of the popup:

Markup:

```
<script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <p>
    <label>Name:<input name="name" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age: <input data-role="numerictextbox" name="age" /></label>
  </p>
</script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { command: "edit" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" }
    }
  },
  editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  },
    toolbar: [{ name: 'create', text: 'Add' }]
});
```

Fiddle demonstrating the issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/XN5rM/1/

The issue is that when you press the Add or Edit buttons, the title bar in the popup says: "Edit".  I want it to say Add when you press the Add button and Edit when you press the Edit button.

Thank you for your time,

Regards,

Scott

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a simple solution, add code to the edit event of the grid to check to see if the model being created when edit is called is a new one or an existing one and set the text accordingly:

```
...

edit: function (e) {
   //add a title
   if (e.model.isNew()) {
       $(".k-window-title").text("Add");
   } else {
       $(".k-window-title").text("Edit");
   }
}

...
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Perfect mate!  Thanks for responding.  Much appreciated!!

Comment: @user2109254 Well you haven't accepted correct answer though you have only commented about correct answer :-)

Comment: @Neil Hibbert, if i want to use my own button to invoke the grid's addnew popup editor, how can i do? thanks

Comment: I am using KendoUI MVVM with grid to add/update/delete. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If the only thing that you need to do is add a title, you should use:

```
editable  : {
    mode : "popup",
    window : {
        title: "Edición",
    }
},
```

You don't need to define a template unless you need to define something else.

Your modified Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XN5rM/2/

Comment: Thanks for responding mate.  I want a custom layout to the form, this is why I am using a template, and it is because I am using a template that the window title says Edit, regardless of if I am adding or editing.  Your proposed solution here will not solve this, however @NeilHibbert will.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond.